# How do I fix my front derailleur?

Tags: chain, gears, derailleur-front

Complete cycling novice here so apologies if this is a stupid question. I went over a bump whilst cycling and knocked my chain off. I think in the process of trying to fix it I must’ve knocked the derailleur out of place because it’s now at such an angle, when it’s in gear 1 it’s pressing against the wheel. When rotating the pedals the chain is now making a continuous clicking noise too. Not sure how to go about fixing it so any advice would be hugely appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Loosen the screw that clamps the derailer to the tube.   Rotate the clamp until it's parallel to the chain rings, then re-tighten.  You may have to tweak it several times to get it exactly right.  (Note that there is a possibility that the derailer is bent, but it's hard to tell from the pictures.)

Answer (score 7):

Shift into the lowest (innermost) gear. This removes the cable tension as much as possible without undoing the pinch bolt and removing the cable

Loosen the bolt that clamps the derailleur to the seat tube, rotate the clamp so the the cage is it's parallel to the chain rings, then re-tighten.

Make sure you do not move the derailleur up or down the seat tube. Usually there is a line of dirt that build up next to the clamp ring so it's easy to see the derailleur position.

You may need to re-adjust the derailleur indexing after straightening it out. The [Park Tool guide](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment) walks you through that process.